# How can I compare 2 arrays in python where one list contains an object in the other list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am working with two arrays in python where one contains a series of points and another contains related points.

Below shows an example of the two arrays
In the first array, The first index is the ID of the point and the second and third index are the X and Y coordinates respectively.
In the second array, the first index is the related point and the second index is the current point.

**Example:**

```
('1', '7.0', '7.0') ('2', '1')

('2', '7.0', '15.0') ('2', '1')
```

What I have coded so far:

```py
def getPairs(listNode,listEdge):
    for node in listNode:
        for edge in listEdge:
            if fromString(node)[0] == fromString(edge)[1]:
                print(fromString(node),fromString(edge))
```

How can I print the current point and the corresponding point on the same line?

Comment: What exactly do you expect to get as output in this example? What is the problem with the code you have so far?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Instead of getting ('1', '7.0', '7.0') ('2', '1'), ('2', '7.0', '15.0') ('2', '1') I want to get ('7.0', '7.0') ('7.0', '15.0')

Comment: So your question is "how to get the second and third item from a tuple with three items", or "how to get the first item from a tuple with two items", respectively?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yeah and then print out the second and third item of both the tuples that are corresponding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are after is to match nodes by id based on the data in edges.

If this is the case then perhaps this might help:

```
nodes = [
    ('1', '7.0', '7.0'),
    ('2', '7.0', '15.0')
]

edges = [
    ('2', '1')
]

def getPairs(nodes, edges):
    pairs = []
    for (related_id, current_id) in edges:
        current_node = [node for node in nodes if node[0] == current_id][0]
        current_coords = (current_node[1], current_node[2])

        related_node = [node for node in nodes if node[0] == related_id][0]
        related_coords = (related_node[1], related_node[2])

        pairs.append((current_coords, related_coords))
    return pairs

for (current_coords, related_coords) in getPairs(nodes, edges):
    print(current_coords, related_coords)
```

Comment: Yes! thank you. I see what I did wrong. I was stuck when comparing the two arrays to find the correct coordinate

Answer (score 0):

Simply use slicing and indexing:

```
array2 = [('1', '7.0', '7.0'), ('2', '7.0', '15.0'), ('3', '7.0', '11.0')]
 
print(array2[0][1:])
print(array2[1][1:])
```

Prints:

```
('7.0', '7.0')
('7.0', '15.0')
```

Comment: ```python
array1 = [('L1', '1'), ('3', '2'), ('1', '3')]
array2 = [('1', '7.0', '7.0'), ('2', '7.0', '15.0'), ('3', '7.0', '11.0')]
```
it looks like this

Comment: @JuiceMelon that better?